# Id of documentset is starting from 2 instead of 1

Tags: document-set, sharepoint-library

In a new document library, when I am creating a new DocumentSet, it is having ID as 2. Is there any reason for it ? Is it not that first item in a document library should have ID as 1 and this values gets incremented for new item created ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked with document sets much, but this is my theory.

Document sets are a beefed up version of a folder. When a folder (or document set in this case) is created the folder has a list item id as well and is presumably created first before any of the files. That's why you'd see the first document in the set with an ID of 2 rather than 1 as the document set folder is actually id 1.

Comment: I haven't created any document. I just created one Document Set in document library. And it has ID as 2

Comment: Right, because my theory is that the document set container, which inherits from Folder, is actually ID 1.